# MPI_Bcast results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, mpi, openmp, openmpi

### **Context**

I've been working on a university project which requires the use of both **OpenMp** and **MPI** to examine a [`.csv` file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13J4fENGbBQbGyAhHtyrIEx2DZl2_oP53) (of 1 million lines) and extract some statistics.

I've managed to write and test a program that works fine on my machine, so I opened an AWS account to tests the actual parallel performance of the program when it runs on multiple nodes.

### **Problem**

When I run the code on a single AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux 2, t2.xlarge) instance, I get a `segmentation fault` that is due to the `MPI_BCast` call, even though the code worked fine on my machine. I really want to understand this problem before extending its execution to other nodes.

I've narrowed down the code that produces this error to the following:

---

```
#define FIN_PATH R"(NYPD_Motor_Vehicle_Collisions.csv)"
#define LINES 955928
#define MAX_LINE_LENGHT 500

...

int main() {
    int RANK;
    int SIZE;
    int THREAD_SUPPORT;

    MPI_Init_thread(nullptr, nullptr, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &THREAD_SUPPORT);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &SIZE);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &RANK);

    int i;

    //Initialize empty dataset
    char ** data = new char*[LINES];

    for(i = 0; i < LINES; ++i)
        data[i] = new char[MAX_LINE_LENGHT] {'\0'};


    // Populate dataset
    if (RANK == 0) {
        string line;
        ifstream fin(FIN_PATH, ios::in);

        getline(fin, line);

        for(i = 0; i < LINES; ++i) {
            getline(fin, line);
            normalize(&line);
            line.copy(data[i], line.size() + 1);
        }
        fin.close();
    }


    // Broadcast dataset to each process
    MPI_Bcast(&data[0][0], LINES * MAX_LINE_LENGHT, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

---

As you can see, I'm reading the file and saving every `char` into a 2d array (because MPI cannot handle strings) which I then broadcast to every process (not elegant, but it helps me avoid major headaches down the road, e.g.: implementing MPI I/O).

I don't get any error when reading the file, only when I reintroduce the MPI_Bcast function.

I made sure that the AWS EC2 Instance had enough RAM (16Gb) so I don't see why this `segmentation fault` would occur, and I'm new to everything (except `c++` programming) so I don't have the tools to debug an error like this yet. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You should allocate one big array of `LINES * MAX_LINE_LENGTH` chars. MPI cannot follow the pointers in 2D arrays that are implemented as an array of pointers. (Ok, it can, but it is a rather involved process and requires the definition of user datatypes) This is a common mistake - you are not the first one to encounter it.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you! That never crossed my mind because it worked fine when I ran the code on my computer. I can't wait to try your suggestion!

Comment: You can allocate one big array and then make an array of pointers into the big array. That way you get the best of both worlds - continuous array for MPI and a convenient 2D array notation for yourself. This is what most HPC users do. See the question that I've closed yours for being duplicate of.

Comment: @HristoIliev It works! Following the instructions provided in the other thread you linked I don't get any segmentation faults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < LINES; ++i)
    data[i] = new char[MAX_LINE_LENGHT] {'\0'};
```

You have allocated a whole bunch of individual strings at different addresses.

```
MPI_Bcast(&data[0][0], LINES * MAX_LINE_LENGHT, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But you told `MPI_Bcast` to send a single object of size `LINES * MAX_LINE_LENGHT`. Nowhere did you create an object like that.

You need to allocate a single object at a single address containing all the data you want to send because that's what `MPI_Bcast` expects.